# Ideas for filling in in ground gutter drains

Tags: plumbing

Back in Sept. of 2019 we had some major sewer issues. They eventually 'relined' the main pipe, thus blocking off the in ground lines that our gutters were hooked up to (with our approval). So now all of our outside gutters are considered 'daylight'. Now we're dealing some MINOR dampness in the basement where these old lines are located. We have top hat covers on the top of the pipes but I'd like a more permanent solution and to help keep them from seeping into our basement. We have extensions approximately 5 feet in length directed away from the house. Something like filling in most of the pipe down to the basement level to help keep the water out. Otherwise our basement is dry. It's just where the old in ground lines are that's the issue. Thank You.

Comment: Help us help you, and give us some pictures.

Comment: I'll add pictures in 4 to 5 days. We're expecting a lot of rain. If there are any breaks in it I'll try my best to grab some pictures.